# Старославянизмы - заимствованные слова или нет?

Tags: лингвистика

Конечно, я знаю, что старославянизмы - это заимствования из старославянского. Интересно отношение к ним на современном этапе. В некоторых источниках можно встретить фразы типа "особый пласт заимствований", "воспринимаются как русские"...
Но более всего смутило задание централизованного тестирования (у нас оно проводилось до 2009 года, материалы готовились централизованно, в федеральных органах, да и сейчас используются для тестирования абитуриентов, поступающих на заочное и дистанционное обучение). Так вот, было задание: в каком тексте нет заимствованных слов?. Методом исключения пришлось выбрать текст,  в котором не было других заимствований, кроме старославянских.
Отсюда и вопрос: однозначно ли отношение в современной лингвистике к старославянизмам как заимствованным словам? И шире: какие слова считать заимствованными? Есть ли разница с точки зрения синхронии - диахронии (вроде: исторически заимствованные, но на современном этапе русские)? Те источники, на которые я натыкаюсь в Сети, не внушают доверия. Интересно Ваше мнение. И может, полезными ссылками поделитесь...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f)](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f), ну вы же знаете историю появления страрославянизмов в русском языке? Документов словам не выписывают, хоть горшком назови, только в печку не ставь. Не о дефинициях же спорить? 
Если бы не тестирование, вообще говорить бы не о чем было. Но  это уже с дядей-составителей надо спрашивать, что они понимают под заимствованиями.

Тут вопрос надо шире ставить. А какие слова вообще можно считать заимствованными? Собственно древнерусских, последовательно сохранившихся (не повторно заимствованных) слов в языке по разным оценкам, если не ошибаюсь, от 10 до 30 процентов, праславянских - 3%, индоевропейских - вообще ничего. Ну и какие из них - заимствования?

Вот насчет синхронии-диахронии... Не знаю, можно ли вообще отнести вашу постановку вопроса к проблеме различий синхронистсвого и диахронистского подходов...

Тут по-другому можно сказать, избегая этих терминов. Есть в принципе два подхода.

Либо заимствованиями считаются только слова, ***воспринимающиеся*** носителями как иностранные, в большинстве своём это слова, попавшие в язык в недавнее время (ну за два века, скажем), которые не успели ещё адаптироваться языком и обычно нуждаются в расшифровке. Это подход составителей словарей иностранных слов. Большинство старославянизмов сюда не попадают, но отдельные можно и отнести. "Кадило", скажем. Мало кто знает, что это слово происходит от праславянского глагола, утерянного в русском.

Либо подход "историков". Заимствования - все слова, ***попавшие*** в язык с определенного момента. Понятно, что срок надо ограничивать, причем разумными датами или событиями. Например, появлением письменности. По большому счету такой подход не дает каких-то практических выходов, это сугубо академический интерес. Но старославянизмы в эту группу заимствований вполне себе попадают.

Answer (score 2):

Не считаю корректным причислять старославянизмы к заимствованиям в отношении современного русского языка. Да, когда старославянский (письменный славянский язык) создавался, он был основан на южнославянском наречии/говоре, но это не был другой язык: отличий в произношении было немногим больше, чем выделяют между говорами внутри русского языка. Можно говорить о заимствованиях в категориях "письменный" (деловой) и "разговорный" (бытовой), то есть какие-то книжные слова переходили в живую речь, какие-то разговорные слова приходили в устоявшийся письменный язык и так далее, но это всё в рамках одного языка, существующего в двух ипостасях.

В любом случае, **современный** литературный язык формировался как синтез древнерусского и старославянского (церковнославянского) с ворохом тюркизмов и прочих заимствований, потому они, по сути, в рамках современного русского исконны. Они могут считаться заимствованными относительно древнерусского, но это уже какая-то сугубо академическая замашка.

Answer (score -3):

**Старославянский язык**? Разве была такая страна Старославяния? Абсолютно очевидно,что заимствования в русском языке от тех народов и культур,с которыми они пересекались.Более 300 лет в составе,да-да именно в составе Орды, безусловно оказали влияние на русский язык. А книги,на котором производились богослужения были на староболгарском. Вот поэтому русский так сильно отличается от других славянских языков: польского,украинского, белорусского. Представитель этих народов, практически без труда поймут рукописный текст, на любом из этих языках,а вот русский и болгарин НЕТ. Ещё Даль писал,что в 100 верстах от Москвы, ни он,ни его не понимали. Безусловно,потому что как датчанин,знавший только русский язык,наречие белорусского, мог понять фино-угорский язык местных жителей? Никак. В качестве того,какое влияние оказал белорусский язык и белорусская культура на формирование русского языка,можно привести лишь несколько примеров: Ломоносов,составлял грамматику русского языка,на основе книг напечатанных в Великом княжестве Литовском (современной Беларуси),в том числе на основе грамматики Мелетия Смотрицкого напечатанной в Вильне в 1619 году.Большое количество жителей,сотни тысяч,в большинстве своём  невольно оказалось на территории Московии (будущей РФ) и самой Москвы,отсюда акающий московский акцент, белорусская (литвинская)знать селилась или скрепляло своё родство с московитами: мать Ивана Ужасного (Грозного), жена Василия 1 и многие другие. Московских царей и их детей обучали белорусские учёные мужи,например Симеон Полоцкий,а первыми книгопечатниками в Московии были белорусы: Ян (Иван) Фёдорович и Пётр Мстиславцев. Поэтому надо писать прямо и честно, а не придумывать очередные мифы. Нет никакого старославянского языка. Есть культуры и языки: белорусские, украинские,татаро-монгольские, которые и формировали русский язык фино-угорских народов будущей РФ.